# What does \b mean in a grep pattern?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

What does this command do?

```
grep "\bi\b" linux.txt
```

What is it searching for?

Comment: It may be obvious, but just in case it is not, here is a note on the (significant) difference between `\<...\>` and `\b...\b`: `You can get unexpected results if you assume the two patterns behave the same... see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844131/emacs-regular-expression-what-and-can-do-that-b-cannot-do/5845285#5845285)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\b` in a regular expression means "word boundary".

With this grep command, you are searching for all words `i` in the file `linux.txt`. `i` can be at the beginning of a line or at the end, or between two space characters in a sentence.

Comment: can be in the begining or in the end?? isn't supposed to be only between spaces??

Comment: I don't find more details about that. But trying by hand with a file containing the lines "i foo" and "bar i", the regexp provided to the grep command above is matching both of them.

Comment: More precisely, not only _space_, but any _non-word character_. Just like the `-w` `--word-regexp` switch does: `grep -w "i" linux.txt`. For example a line like "<i>italic</i>" also matches.

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` (word boundary) anchor can be used in place of `\<` and `\>` to signify the beginning or end of a word.

If this is the content of a `file`:

```
Hi
this
is test file
to carry out few regular expressions
```

Then:

```
$ grep -e '\breg' file
to carry out few regular expressions
```

Answer (score 0):

Note about `\b` , `\<`, `\>`:

*When used inside quotes (`""` or `''`)*,  `\b` and `\<`,`\>` work as word boundaries, as explained above.
*When quotes are not used*, `\\b` has to be used instead of `\b`.

**Examples**:
`grep i` works but does not find whole words only
`grep \bi\b` does not work
`grep \\bi\\b` works
`grep "\bi\b"` works and it is the same as `grep "\<i\>"`

Comment: Welcome to the site. If your post is meant to improve an existing answer rather than suggesting a different kind of solution, please don't post it as a new answer. Rather, place a comment below the answer you want to improve, or submit an edit suggestion that would incorporate your improvements to that answer.